# Bounds on a sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Let $\operatorname{frac}(n)$ denote the fractional part of a positive integer n. Then, which are the best known bounds for

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \operatorname{frac}\Big( \frac{n}{k}\Big)$$

?

The only information I could find relates this expression to Dirichlet Divisors Problem. Is there any better bound?

Comment: By trial and error, I have the following crude bounds:$$n\ln n-4n^{1.1}<\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{frac}(n/k)<n+n\ln n-3n^{1.1}$$but with no explanation other than trial and error.

Comment: What is your bound obtained from Dirichlet's divisor problem?

Comment: @SimpleArt Your upper bound eventually becomes negative.

Comment: @i707107 Very good point.  I totally made it up out of thin air via graphing.

Comment: @user3141592  Your question is essentially an equivalent one to the Dirichlet's Divisor Problem. So, I wouldn't expect any "better" bound than the one obtained by the DDP. But, still I want to know which bound you obtained so far.

Comment: If I understand i707107's comment, you need to combine $ \left\{ y \right\}=y- \lfloor y\rfloor$, with $\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)$, where $d(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}1$ and search in internet about recent progress on Dirichlet Divisor problem (for example the entry of MathWorld). I believe that the more important is that you learn the method of summation if you don't know it (see Murty, *Introduction to analytic number theory* in YouTube from the offcial channel **matsciencechannel**, you need to study Lecture 01 Partial summation formula and applications, and at least of lecture 06 from start to minute 24).

Comment: @i707107 I got that using $$H_n= \log{n} +\gamma +\epsilon_0$$ , $$f(n)=n(1 - \gamma) - E(n) + \epsilon_0$$, being $E(n)$ the error term on DDP.

Comment: And $\epsilon_0$ is approximately equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @user3141592 Great. Current knowledge about $E(n)$ is, $E(n)=O(n^{\theta+\epsilon})$ where $\frac14 \leq \inf \theta \leq \frac{131}{416}$.

Comment: @i707107 And what about $\epsilon_0$? Are there any lower/upper bounds about it?

Comment: @user3141592 $\epsilon_0 = O(\frac1n)$, and $f(n) = n(1-\gamma) - E(n) + n \epsilon_0$ is a correct formula. Since $n\epsilon_0 = O(1)$, it is dominated by $E(n)$.